# Reduce row length of Function according to "Clean Code" when using Stream API in Java

Tags: java, coding-style

I am currently studying the book "Clean Code" and it states that every function should have less than 5 lines of code.

At the same time I am using Java with Spring Boot and I am trying to figure out how this statement could be applied to this lines of code.

```java
public Cart addToCart(String cartId, Integer itemId) {
    Cart cart = cartRepository.findById(cartId)
            .orElseGet(() -> new Cart(cartId));

    cart.getCartItems().stream()
            .filter(cartItem -> cartItem.getItem().getId().equals(itemId))
            .findAny()
            .map(cartItem -> {
                cartItem.increment();
                return cart;
            })
            .orElseGet(() -> {
                Item item = this.itemRepository.findById(itemId)
                        .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("Can't seem to find Item type" + itemId));
                cart.getCartItems().add(new CartItem(item, cart));
                return cart;
            });

    return this.cartRepository.save(cart);
}
```

I'm thinking of something like this:

```java
public Cart addToCart(String cartId, Integer itemId) {
    Cart temp_cart = cartRepository.findById(cartId)
            .orElseGet(() -> new Cart(cartId));

    Cart cart = addItemToCartOrThrowItemNotFoundError(temp_cart, itemId);

    return this.cartRepository.save(cart);
}

private Cart addItemToCartOrThrowItemNotFoundError(Cart cart, Integer itemId) {
    cart.getCartItems().stream()
            .filter(cartItem -> cartItem.getItem().getId().equals(itemId))
            .findAny()
            .map(cartItem -> {
                cartItem.increment();
                return cart;
            })
            .orElseGet(() -> {
                Item item = this.itemRepository.findById(itemId)
                        .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("Can't seem to find Item type" + itemId));
                cart.getCartItems().add(new CartItem(item, cart));
                return cart;
            });
    return cart;
}
```

But then I don't know how to split up the function addItemToCartOrThrowItemNotFoundError while preserving the use of Stream API.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: You can't. There are things that are impossible, when you give out blanket statements like "functions should be less than 5 lines". Especially since Java has methods not functions, and this is a matter of opinion and not some kind of universal rule.

Comment: For some further insights on why advice from Clean Code is somewhat likely to run into gritted teeth by experienced programmers, [this sums it up nicely](https://qntm.org/clean).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't read the book, but the suggestion that "every function should have less than 5 lines of code" or names like `addItemToCartOrThrowItemNotFoundError` seems very unhelpful.

Your code highlights a case where use of `Stream` has lead to very awkward to follow code. You should try simple refactoring of the important actions to simply named helper functions, something like:

```
public Cart addToCart(String cartId, Integer itemId) {
    
    Cart cart = cartRepository.findById(cartId)
                              .orElseGet(() -> new Cart(cartId));
    
    Item item = cart.findItem(itemId)
                    .orElseGet(() -> cart.addItem(itemId))
                    .increment();
    
    return this.cartRepository.save(cart);
}
```

As you can see you'd need to implement `findItem(Integer itemId)` and `addItem(Integer itemId)` based on the 2 main branches of your block starting `cart.getCartItems().stream() ...`, and ensure that the counter for new item is set to zero so that `item.increment()` works correctly inside `addToCart` and not called inside `findItem`.

Comment: "implement `findItem(Integer itemId)` and `addItem(Integer itemId)`" - I agree with this idea, that's the right way to go. The code provided in the question exposes broken encapsulation - `cart.getCartItems().add(new CartItem(item, cart))` (this can also be considered as a violation of the Information expert principle, only `Cart` object should manage its data).